# xUnit InMemoryDatabase Test failure: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xunit, in-memory-database, ef-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I run Unit-Tests on TFS in a CI environment, today it failed with the following exception:

```
Error:
  System.InvalidOperationException : Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
Stacktrace:
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.GetDisplayName(Type type)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FindEntityType(Type type)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.EntityEqualityRewritingExpressionVisitor.RewriteEntityEquality(ExpressionType nodeType, Expression left, Expression right)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.EntityEqualityRewritingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.EntityEqualityRewritingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
    at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
    at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
    at Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.TransformExpressions(Func`2 transformation)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryOptimizer.Optimize(QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext, QueryModel queryModel)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.OptimizeQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, Boolean asyncQuery)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression query, IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDatabase database, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
    at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
    at ModelNamespace.SomeRepository.TestMethod()
    at TestNamespace.SomeRepositoryTest.TestMethod_Test()
```

After that I started the same build on the same commit again and it succeeded. Odd isn't it?

### How the Tests are built up

To set up InMemoryDatabases, we use the following helper Class:

```
public class DbContextTestHelper
{
    public static DbContextOptions<CustomContext> PrepareData(Action<CustomContext> createData)
    {
        var options = CreateDbContextOptions();
        SaveData(options, createData);
        return options;
    }

    private static void SaveData(DbContextOptions<CustomContext> options, Action<CustomContext> createData)
    {
        // Insert seed data into the database using one instance of the context
        using (var context = new CustomContext(options))
        {
            createData.Invoke(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static DbContextOptions<CustomContext> CreateDbContextOptions()
    {
        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CustomContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid()
                .ToString()) //Database with same name gets reused, so let's isolate the tests from each other...
            .Options;
    }
}
```

So now we have many Tests we build up like this:

```
public class SomeRepositoryTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestMethod_Test()
    {
        var options = DbContextTestHelper.PrepareData(context =>
        {
            // do some initialisation
        });
        // Use a clean instance of the context to run the test
        using (var context = new CustomContext(options))
        {
            var testee = new SomeRepository(context);
            await testee.TestMethod(); // InvalidOperationException from above
            // Assert something
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there are many cases where we create those `DbContextOptions<CustomContext>` and naturally they run parallel because of the built-in functionality that `xUnit` provides (yes of course not in the same class but for many test classes).

### My Question

As far as I can tell there are few possibilities of why this can sometimes cause an exception:

- the GUID's generated to ensure different instances of InMemoryDatabases are duplicates. However I'd rather not believe this.
- there is a bug in the InMememory Database System
- We are using InMemoryDatabases wrong

Do you know what's going on?

### Edit 1:

As Requested, here's the `TestMethod()` where `System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable'1 source)` gets called.

```
    public void TestMethod(SomeObject someObject, List<DateTime> dates, bool someOption)
    {
        var res = _dbContext.SomeSet.Where(o =>
            o.SomeObject.Equals(someObject) && dates.Contains(o.DateTime) && o.SomeOption == someOption);
        if (res.Any()) // at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source) 
        {
            _dbContext.SomeSet.RemoveRange(res);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be an issue in `EntityFrameworkCore` https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2453. One suggested fix is to use `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: @obl the point is, that im not at all accessing any dictionary. I only have an InMemoryDB and a DbContext. There are only `DbSet<T>` which I access. So im not really able to change this behavior.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you find the `System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable\`1 source)` query mentioned in the stack trace and post it?

Comment: @obl added it. hope it helps